# User is not getting tracked

Tags: c#, kinect, greenfoot

I am developing a game using greenfoot and kinect. The theme of the game is to catch the falling apples with the basket.The basket movement should happen via kinect. The problem is I am not getting tracked by the kinect.

```
UserData user= world.getTrackedUser();
GreenfootImage image1=world.getThumbnail();
System.out.println(image1 +"image");
System.out.println(user+"user");//here i am getting it as null
if(user!=null){
    if(user.getNearestJoint()==Joint.RIGHT_HAND)
    {
        Joint rightHand= user.getJoint(Joint.RIGHT_HAND);
        getImage().drawImage(image1,rightHand.getX(),rightHand.getY());
    }else
    if(user.getNearestJoint()==Joint.LEFT_HAND){
        Joint leftHand=user.getJoint(Joint.LEFT_HAND);
        getImage().drawImage(image1,leftHand.getX(),leftHand.getY());
    }
```

Comment: We might need a little bit more code then this. How are you initializing your Kinect? How are you binding your event handlers etc?

Comment: Yea I did.Th code is huge.So i jus posted the part where i am getting an exception

Comment: And what is the actual exception?

Comment: I commented in the code where i am getting this exception(null pointer exception)

Comment: It just appears your user object is null. So you will have to check what's going wrong in the getTrackeduser() function.